# Is there a "double" try and catch block?

Tags: kotlin, try-catch

Is there a way to use a `try-catch` in Kotlin like this

```
try {
 // First try, if it throws an exception, try next try block
} try {
 // Second try, if it throws an exception, too, go to exception block
} catch (e: Exception) {
 // Handle exception
}
```

### Edit

So, let's say there are two encryption algorithms and one encrypted string, but you do not know which one has been used to encrypt that string. Those algorithms are very specific and without `try-catch` the app would crash. That's why I need to go through two `try` blocks.

Comment: You need to put the second try into the first catch. And then add its own catch clause.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, business-wise?

Comment: @Joffrey I added a comment to the question. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: What are you doing to handle those exceptions? If you don't get any specific info from them, and don't rethrow, I believe you should just extract 2 functions and convert exception-throwing code into null result which is more convenient to chain. It's hard to give specific help if you don't provide specific code. Likely the structure of the code should be changed, but depending on what you do inside, the answer might be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid code duplicating by repeating your *try*-block in your *catch*-block (as mentioned by @luk2302), you should consider adding a retry-parameter to your function and call it recursively, like:

```
fun doStuff(retry: Boolean = true) {
  try {
    ...
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    if (retry)
      return doStuff(retry = false)
    ... // handle exception
  }
```

For multiple retries, you can use an Int instead and decrement until you hit 0.

Comment: thanks. This one seems to be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to add kind of "attempts threshold" you could use something like that:

```
private var attempts = 0

fun doSomething() {
    try {
        // your code with potential exception
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        if (++attempts > 1) // handle exception
        else doSomething()
    }
}
```

If you really **need** a nested `try-catch` then you can follow the approach by @luk2302. But, to be honest, it looks a little bit doubtful in terms of code cleanliness:

```
fun doSomething() {
    try {
        // your code with potential exception
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        try {
            // your code with potential exception
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Catching `Exception` is bad practice in general. If you're not writing some kind of framework code that rethrows the exceptions in a different form, you should know what business exception can be thrown and only catch those. Let the rest of the code do the work to handle other types of exceptions.

You haven't shared the code from the catch block, but given that you catch the general `Exception`, it seems that you don't extract information about the exact exception nor re-throw. In that case, it seems to me that you should just be extracting stuff into functions that return null in case of wrong algorithm, and not even have this problem in the first place:

```kotlin
fun decrypt(msg: String): String {
    return decryptWithAlgo1OrNull(msg) ?: decryptWithAlgo2OrNull(msg) ?: handleFailureOfBoth()
}

private fun decryptWithAlgo1OrNull(msg: String): String? = try {
    // algo 1 decyrption
} catch (e: SpecificAlgo1Exception) {
    null
}
private fun decryptWithAlgo2OrNull(msg: String): String? = try {
    // algo 2 decyrption
} catch (e: SpecificAlgo2Exception) {
    null
}
```

You might not need to do that for the second function, but I figured it would be more symmetrical.